# Why memory sink writes nothing in append mode?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I used Spark's structured streaming to stream messages from Kafka. The data was then aggregated, and wrote to a memory sink with append mode. However, when I tried to query the memory, it returned nothing. Below are the code:

```
result  =    model
            .withColumn("timeStamp", col("startTimeStamp").cast("timestamp"))
            .withWatermark("timeStamp", "5 minutes")
            .groupBy(window(col("timeStamp"), "5 minutes").alias("window"))
            .agg(
                count("*").alias("total")
            );

    // writing to memory
    StreamingQuery query = result.writeStream()
                .outputMode(OutputMode.Append())
                .queryName("datatable")
                .format("memory")
                .start();

    // query data in memory
    new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            sparkSession.sql("SELECT * FROM datatable").show();
        }
    }, 10000, 10000);
```

The result is always:

```
|window|total|
+------+-----+
+------+-----+
```

If I used `outputMode = complete`, then I could get the aggregated data. But that's not my choice as the requirement is to use append mode.

Is there any problem with the code?
Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

In append mode,

> The output of a windowed aggregation is delayed the late threshold specified in `withWatermark()`

In your case, the delay is 5 minutes, I know nothing about your input data, but I guess you probably need to wait for 5 minutes.

I suggest you read (again?) [the docs for Structured Streaming](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#basic-operations---selection-projection-aggregation):

Comment: I waited for more than 5 minutes, and it is the same results. And from my understanding, the threshold depends on the timestamp value in the message, not on the timestamp when the messages arrive; and in my case, I sent all messages at once, so it basically that after a few seconds, the result should be finalized to the Result Table. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks.

Comment: I see. The issue is that you just triggered one batch. Please send more messages to trigger another batch so that the windowed aggregation can get a chance to emit results.

Comment: Thanks, It did finalize the results after sending the second batch. So the structured stream only finalizes the result after processing a batch? Is there any chance for it to finalize as soon as it receives message with the timestamp larger than the threshold? I think it would be better that way.